# Disable input field based on a drop down selection trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="form-group form-animate-text col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" >
    <select class="form-text" id="val_equipfc"  name="val_equipfc"  onChange="checkOption(this)" required>
        <option value = "A">Yes</option>
        <option value = "B">No</option>
    </select>
    <span class="bar"></span> 
    <label><span style="color:red">*</span>With Equipment?</span></label>
</div>
```

This is my select class and this is the input field div

```
<div class="form-group form-animate-text col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6" >
    <input type="text" class="form-text" id="val_equipnofc" name="val_equipnofc">
    <span class="bar"></span> 
    <label><span style="color:red">*</span>Number of Equipment/s</label>
</div>
```

The jquery in disabling input text field as I clicked No in the dropdown menu is this:

```
function checkOption(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementById("val_equipnofc");
    input.disabled = obj.value == "B";
}
```

I wonder what's wrong, when I searched for how to do it, my code is similar in those on the net please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `<span style="color:red">*</span>With Equipment?</span>` is correct?

Comment: It's just tells that the text field is mandatory

Comment: This is what you have coded right? `input.disabled = obj.value == "B";
` ? `input.disabled` will be true when value of select is `"B"`

Comment: Correct source code from <label><span style="color:red">*</span>With Equipment?</span></label> to <label><span style="color:red">*</span>With Equipment?</label>

Comment: I changed it but it isn't disabled when i choose No in the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

First of all you seem to have a markup problem (see Question comments)

Then I would add the event listener with JavaScript to avoid having problems with JS not being loaded

```
document.getElementById ("val_equipfc").addEventListener ("change", ...)
```

and access the new value using the `this` keyword.

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/7xav90f6/)

---

PS: Why not use a Checkbox instead of a Dropdown if you only have a Yes/No option

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Jquery` then you can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#val_equipfc').change(function(){
    $('#val_equipnofc').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "B");
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/k4k24tq2/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is the full HTML Markup.

Please test it. This has to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This should work</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group form-animate-text col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <select class="form-text" id="val_equipfc" name="val_equipfc" onChange="checkOption(this)" required>
            <option value="A">Yes</option>
            <option value="B">No</option>
        </select>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><span style="color:red">*</span>With Equipment?</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-animate-text col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-text" id="val_equipnofc" name="val_equipnofc">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><span style="color: red">*</span>Number of Equipment/s</label>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkOption(obj) {
            var input = document.getElementById("val_equipnofc");
            input.disabled = obj.value == "B";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces:

Yes state:

[image]

No state:

[image]